# jQuery fadeIn and fadeOut takes 50% of processor

Tags: javascript, jquery, fadein, fadeout

I have 135 html elements which I want to be faded in and out randomly, so I wrote this code for it:

```
setInterval(function() {
    ggg = Math.floor(Math.random() * (50 - 1 + 1) + 1);
    $("#f" + ggg).fadeIn(500, function() {  });
    $("#f" + ggg).fadeOut(500);
}, 300);


setInterval(function() {
    ggg = Math.floor(Math.random() * (100 - 50 + 1) + 50);
    $("#f" + ggg).fadeIn(500, function() {  });
    $("#f" + ggg).fadeOut(500); 
}, 300);

setInterval(function() {
    ggg = Math.floor(Math.random() * (135 - 100 + 1) + 100);
    $("#f" + ggg).fadeIn(500, function() {   });
    $("#f" + ggg).fadeOut(500);
}, 300);
```

But the problem is that it takes 50 percent of my i7 on Macbook Pro, even though there is no problem on a Windows laptop. Can someone rewrite the code for better performance?

Comment: You're calling them every 300ms but the animation takes 1 second, therefor you're looping and looping and looping and looping and.... before it even gets finished the 1st time.

Comment: how many `id="#f###"` are there?

Answer (score 0):

```
animate = function() {
  ggg = Math.floor(Math.random() * (100 - 50 + 1) + 50);
  $("#f" + ggg).fadeIn(500, function() {
  $("#f" + ggg).fadeOut(500,animate); 
  })
}
animate();
```

To delay, make this modification:

```
  $("#f" + ggg).delay(300).fadeOut(500,animate);
```

You could also use `.stop(true,true)` to clear the queue before starting another animation.

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#f" + ggg).animate({ opacity: 0 }, 500, function() {
    $("#f" + ggg).animate({ opacity: 1 }, 500)
});
```

Perhaps you're getting higher speed with animate, but idk. It's not uncommon for javascript to even slow down an i7 (perhaps browser related performance?)

Answer (score 0):

In addition to kicking off a 1-second animation every 300ms (which makes little sense), it also appears that you're expecting the `fadeIn` and `fadeOut` functions to run synchronously.

This code:

```
$("#f" + ggg).fadeIn(500, function() {  });
$("#f" + ggg).fadeOut(500);
```

Will start a half-second fade-in, then *immediately* overwrite it with a half-second fade-out. I'm not even sure what that does.

That empty function you pass to `fadeIn` is the callback to do when it's complete... thats where you want to put the `fadeOut`:

```
$("#f" + ggg).fadeIn(500, function() {
    $("#f" + ggg).fadeOut(500);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

My guess would be that the reason is the stacking of the animation calls.

You set a Interval which calls a function every 300 Milliseconds, which start 2 animations with a duration of of 500+500 Milliseconds.

Also you could do all 3 animation calls in one function.
And maybe there might be a better way to select your object that you want to animate? Random might not be the most efficient way.

Maybe this might already do the trick (untested)

```
function animateStuff(){
    ggg = Math.floor(Math.random() * (50 -1 + 1) + 1);
    $("#f" + ggg).fadeOut(500, function(){
        $(this).fadeIn(500);
    });

    ggg = Math.floor(Math.random() * (100 -1 + 1) + 1);
    $("#f" + ggg).fadeOut(500, function(){
        $(this).fadeIn(500);
    });

    ggg = Math.floor(Math.random() * (135 -1 + 1) + 1);
    $("#f" + ggg).fadeOut(500, function(){
        $(this).fadeIn(500);
    });
}

setInterval(function(){
    animateStuff();
}, 1000);
```

Answer (score 0):

Give your elements a class, cache your elements, randomize your jQuery object and then fade them in and out.

```
var els = $(".random");
var $random = shuffleArray( els );

$random.each( function( ) {
    var max = 4000;
    var min = 1000;
    var duration = Math.floor( Math.random() * ( max - min + 1) + min );
    $(this).delay( duration ).fadeTo( 1000, 1, function( ) {
        $(this).delay( duration ).fadeTo( 1000, 0 );
    });
});
```

Shuffling function found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2450954/how-to-randomize-shuffle-a-javascript-array)

```
/**
 * Randomize array element order in-place.
 * Using Fisher-Yates shuffle algorithm.
 */
function shuffleArray(array) {
    for (var i = array.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
        var j = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i + 1));
        var temp = array[i];
        array[i] = array[j];
        array[j] = temp;
    }
    return array;
}
```

Fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/zDFe9/5/)